# How Can I Automatically Populate SQLAlchemy Database Fields? (Flask-SQLAlchemy)

Tags: database, postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I've got a simple User model, defined like so:

```
# models.py
from datetime import datetime
from myapp import db

class User(db.Model):
  id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
  email = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=True)
  password = db.Column(db.String(100))
  date_updated = db.Column(db.DateTime())

  def __init__(self, email, password, date_updated=None):
    self.email = email
    self.password = password
    self.date_updated = datetime.utcnow()
```

When I create a new User object, my `date_updated` field gets set to the current time. What I'd like to do is make it so that *whenever* I save changes to my User object my `date_updated` field is set to the current time automatically.

I've scoured the documentation, but for the life of me I can't seem to find any references to this. I'm very new to SQLAlchemy, so I really have no prior experience to draw from.

Would love some feedback, thank you.

Comment: Such fields are typically known as audit or record timestamp fields. Searching with those terms may reveal more.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Just add `server_default` or `default` argument to the column fields:

```
created_on = db.Column(db.DateTime, server_default=db.func.now())
updated_on = db.Column(db.DateTime, server_default=db.func.now(), server_onupdate=db.func.now())
```

I prefer the `{created,updated}_on` column names. ;)

SQLAlchemy docs about [column insert/update defaults](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/core/defaults.html#server-side-defaults).

**[Edit]:** Updated code to use `server_default` arguments in the code.

**[Edit 2]:** Replaced `onupdate` with `server_onupdate` arguments.

Comment: Hi, would you please advise how to modify the timezone since the `db.func.now()` return the timestamp out of my timezone. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I found simply `updated_on = db.Column(db.DateTime, onupdate=datetime.datetime.now)` resolve the timezone issue according to [this](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/core/defaults.html#server-side-defaults) .

Comment: Why use `server_default`?  Docs are wordy but useless.  Guessing from the name that it occurs at the database?

Comment: `server_default` is the server side value issued in the SQL during a `create_table` instruction, in contrast to the `default` value which refers to the python side of the model. 

as in 
http://alembic.zzzcomputing.com/en/latest/ops.html 

* In particular, default values to be created on the database side are specified using the `server_default` parameter, and not `default` which only specifies Python-side defaults*

Comment: Don't work on mysql 5.5 , because it doesn't support `DATETIME DEFAULT now()` . Any other way ?

Comment: @Mithril Upgrade? Or you could try `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` as an alternative for `now()`, though it might be also unsupported on first 5.5.x versions.

Answer (score 7):

```
date_created  = db.Column(db.DateTime,  default=db.func.current_timestamp())
date_modified = db.Column(db.DateTime,  default=db.func.current_timestamp(),
                                       onupdate=db.func.current_timestamp())
```

Comment: Some justification for this variant, found here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sqlalchemy/7A6LCOKnrVY

Comment: I am using PostgreSQL 14+ and this worked!